# Color correcting/balancing for mosaic hyperspectral raster images

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, mosaic, envi

I have two rasters (hyperspectral images with 810 bands). I need to mosaic them, and I am doing it in ArcMap using Data management tools>Raster>raster dataset>create raster dataset>mosaic.  I am using the following options

1. For the mosaic type: the method used for mosaic overlap areas:  blend: The output cell value of the overlapping areas will be a horizontally weighted calculation of the cell values in the overlapping area.
2. For the color map: MATCH —Consider all colormaps when mosaicking. If all possible values are already in use (for the bit depth), it will try to match the value to the closest color available.
3. Matching Method: HISTOGRAM_MATCHING —This method will match the histogram of the reference overlap area to the source overlap area and then apply the transformation to the entire destination dataset.
4. mosaicking_tolerance:  zero tolerance because I needed resampling of the pixel due to incorrect pixel alignment.

Nevertheless, I get this final mosaic with substantial RGB color differences.
[image]

Is there a way to do a good-looking mosaic?